# LINQ to SQL Storing query results in a variable

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, data-retrieval

For example I am searching for a specific persons ID and I want to store that ID to a local variable or instance variable. How do I retrieve Query results and stores them in a int Variable with LINQ to SQL? 
Assuming we have this query

```
from user in dbo.DoctorsName
where doctorsName  = "Foo Bar"
select DOC_ID;
```

Comment: what is DOC_ID? I really dont understand what you want? do you want to get the results from DB and assign them to local variables?

Comment: DOC_ID is simply a an ID, I want to retrieve an ID where the doctors name is "Foo Bar"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`FirstOrDefault()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482.aspx) like this:

```
var results = from user in dbo.DoctorsName
              where user.doctorsName  == "Foo Bar"
              select user;

string personName = results.FirstOrDefault().Name;
```

Comment: That's it? how would I execute the query? there's no insertOnSubmit? What if i am looking for a table ID? not a String?

Comment: @user962206, Why did you need `insertOnSubmit()`?? and you can select any of the `user` properties as well like `int ID = results.FirstOrDefault().ID` this will give you one value for the one row selected.

Comment: That's the code I need? no more? that's just it? no more executeQuery(results) like in java?

Comment: @user962206, no more, just like this.

Answer (score 0):

This should help.

```
var name = dbo.DoctorsName.Where(item => item.doctorsName = "Foo Bar").Select(item => item.Name).FirstOrDefault();
```

If there are no records for your condition then using FirstOrDefault() can throw an exception. For this you can try using -

```
var namelist = dbo.DoctorsName.Where(item => item.doctorsName = "Foo Bar").Select(item => item.Name);

If(namelist.Count() > 0)
   var name = namelist.Fisrt();
```

Comment: `FirstOrDefault` in ur first code snippet will not throw exception because u are selecting `item.Name` which is of type string. if there is no matching record, it will simply return null which is `default` for string type

Answer (score 0):

Similar to this:

```
var ticketDepartment = from t in dt_tickets.AsEnumerable()
                       where t.Field<string>("MID") == mid
                       select new { department = t.Field<string>("Department") };
```

and now you have your variable in ticketDepartment.department